# What is the slang meaning of chatière?

Tags: traduction, argot

I was reading a New Yorker article about the "city" under Paris it was mentioned that there is another meaning besides cat flap for chatière. However my google-fu appears to be weak today, and I can't seem to figure out what it is.

from [The Invisible City Under Paris](https://www.newyorker.com/news/dispatch/the-invisible-city-beneath-paris?utm_source=pocket-newtab)

> Chatière means cat-flap, as well as something a bit less polite than
>   that...

Comment: I've never heard anyone saying `chatière` in a slang way, I didn't even know it could have this meaning of a vagina, even if, of course, like any object that can be "penetrated", you can imagine this meaning I guess. The slang word almost everyone uses for vagina is `chatte`, which means "female cat" and can be seen as the equivalent of "pussy" in English, and most people avoid using it in its first meaning because of the strong connotation (like "pussy", "ass", or "bitch" in English I guess).

Comment: I'd rather think that "chatte" is the vulva rather than the vagina.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a plentiful crop of  synonyms   for this argot word; those below come from this [reference](http://dictionnaire.sensagent.leparisien.fr/chati%C3%A8re/fr-fr/). It means 
"sexe de la femme", according to the synonyms.

chatière (n.f.) (argotique)

foune, berlingot  (argotique), chagatte  (Pej Arg Pop), chatte  (vulgaire), con  (argotique, vulgaire), divertissoire  (argotique), écu  (argotique), foufoune  (familier), frifri  (argotique), losange  (familier, figuré), mimi  (familier), minette  (familier), minou  (familier), minouche  (familier), moule  (argotique, populaire), salle des fêtes  (argotique), trou  (argotique), zézette  (enfantin, familier), zigouigoui  (argotique)

foune : ([ref](http://dictionnaire.sensagent.leparisien.fr/foune/fr-fr/)), sexe de la femme
berlingot : [ref](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=berlingot+argot&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwja47iZ17TiAhXk8OAKHcZ-BpYQ1QIoAHoECAoQAQ&biw=1846&bih=751), as above
chagatte: [ref](https://dico-des-mots.com/definitions/chagatte.html), as above
…

Comment: On peut le dire *grossier*,  le ***con*** chanté par Brassens, mais en aucun cas vulgaire. Un personnage vulgaire trouvera des sous-entendus vulgaires à chaque mot de la vie courante, mais le mot *con* lui-même ne l’est pas.

Comment: @cl-r Dans *Le Blason*, Brassens déplore qu'on ait donné à cette partie de l'anatomie le même nom qu'une foule de gens, et refuse à employer le mot *con* dans ce sens-là.

Comment: It can be noted that it's one of the less used terms.

Comment: I must admit I didn't even suspect some of these words to designate the female genitals. Some are certainly very outdated and "con" is one of them from where I see it...

Comment: @Damien … bien sûr, mais même quand il devient insulte, il n’est que *grossier* [c’est un « gros mot » que l’on interdit de prononcer aux enfants], c’est sa mise au féminin ou le suffixe *-nard* qui le rend *vulgaire*.

Comment: @cl-r Selon moi, *con* n'est pas vulgaire pour désigner un malcomprenant, mais le devient pour désigner les organes génitaux féminins. Au minimum, pas très élégant

Comment: @cl-r  Le TLFi confirme l'impression de vulgarité que me donne ce mot quand on parle de la personne de peu d'intelligence : B. P. méton., au fig., vulg. [P. réf. au sexe de la femme pris comme symbole de l'impuissance et de la passivité]. Il est vulgaire à mon avis même lorsqu'il est utilisé pour exprimer du mépris en parlant d'une personne dont les choix et décisions sont totalement contraires aux nôtres d'une façon qui nous parait anormale, bornée, ou méchante. Dans le sens premier aussi ce mot est à éviter :  (TLFi) A. Subst., **trivial**.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, my, these answers are all (understandably) on the wrong track entirely.  I am an American linguist who lives in Paris.  I can tell you that the slang term "chatiere" (cat flap) is not related to "chatte" (pussy).  It is Parisian slang for a bisexual person, because a cat flap "swings both ways".

Comment: *Chatière* is  also a slang word for the female sex, nothing in the New-Yorker article implies your answer is better and the other is "on the wrong track entirely".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: intersting. It would be better to have a source or at least some detail : is it recent slang or not ? Though I never heard "chatière" used for "chatte", it would not be suprising to have some variation around a very common slang word like this one.

Answer (score 0):

A chatière in the context of the Paris Catacombs is a small hole or tunnel that has been dug by Cataphiles through a barrier or wall or to join two layers of tunnels together. The aim is to provide access where it was previously not possible.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question!

Comment: That's not what the question is asking.